# Elasticsearch - Using groovy script within function_score and access field payload

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I am trying to understand what is the best way to access the payload while using groovy script.

I want to do something like this:

```
sum = 0;
categories  = doc['category'].values; 
for (category in categories){
   sum += category.payload
}
return sum;
```

**Edit**:
Thanks to @Val and @Lee H I got to this point where I can actually access the payloads. But the suggested solution was to use _index which is not what I am looking for, _index give access to statistics in the scope of the index, and not for a specific document.

I want to go over every document, and take its payload and multiply it with some constant lets say.

when doing this: _index['category'].get('term', _PAYLOADS) I will get a list of all payloads of "term", which will is not what I am looking for.

So is there a way to access a field payload from the scope of a document?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for
[term positions and payloads](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_positions_offsets_and_payloads)
it shows an example accessing the payloads for a field

Copying the last example here:

```
Example: sums up all payloads for the term foo.

termInfo = _index['my_field'].get('foo',_PAYLOADS);
score = 0;
for (pos in termInfo) {
    score = score + pos.payloadAsInt(0);
}
return score;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [advanced scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html) and the `_index` context variable.

And Groovy is here to help with a nice one-liner:

```
return _index['category'].get('term', _PAYLOADS).sum {it.payloadAsInt(0)}
```

Comment: Actually when thinking about it, it doesn't solve my problem..:-| _index give me access to statistics in the scope of the index, and not for a specific document. I want to go on every document, and take its payload and multiply it with some constant lets say. when doing this: _index['category'].get('term', _PAYLOADS) I will get a list of all payloads of "term", which will is not what I am looking for. what do you think? how can I access the payload of a document from the document scope and not the index?

Comment: Hmm, let me think about this. In the meantime, you should update your question to clarify your expectations based on what you just commented.

Comment: Do you have an idea? @Val